# Архивирование с помощью Python, Windows и 7zip

Tags: python, cmd, zip, архивация

Здравствуйте! Хочу организовать архивирование файлов с помощью программы 7-zip. И не понимаю почему код не работает. Путь к 7z в PATH я прописал. Все каталоги созданы, код из `print(zip_command)` при копировании в командную строку работает. Вот код:

```
zip_command = "7z a -tzip -ssw -mx1 -pPassword -r0 "'"C:\\becap prog"'" "'"C:\Test for prog"'" && pause"
print(zip_command)
if os.system(zip_command) == 0:
    print('Резервная копия успешно создана')
else:
    print('Создание резервной копии НЕ УДАЛОСЬ')
```

Comment: А без pause работает?

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов Нет, не работает.

Comment: для начала без Питона добейтесь, чтобы команда работала.Потом просто как есть внутрь `r''` строки вставьте.  Не обязательно `cmd.exe` запускать, [можно через subprocess только 7z запустить](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2366917/4279) (pause уберите)

Comment: В примере страшная мешанина кавычек в первой строке. Там 5!!! написанных подряд  строк, которые интерпретатор соединяет в одну. Надо просто поставить одиночные внешние кавычки, тогда внутри использовать двойные без каких-либо проблем.